# [AWS][Systems Manager] Restart instances with Dependency Order

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, powershell

Basic case:
Let's say I have 5 instances with 5 different application component on them.
When I have to perform a restart of the whole product I need to chain stop/start in a specific order usually through PowerShell remoting.
Is there a way to write this with dependencies in SystemsManager different functionalities.
So execute Service-Stop on instance A, then when and if completed* on instance B, etc.

Complex case:
Handle RDS DB snapshots before or after per DB not RDS instance (PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it can be done in the Automation section, not that easy, but looks promising, I will remove the answer if something better is proposed.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-actions.html